# Google Cloud Source Repositories: change default branch?

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

With GCP CSR, is it possible to change the default branch for a repository from `master` to something else? This doesn't have much bearing on functionality other than the branch that's first displayed in the CSR UI. However, it's something I can change in GitHub.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot change the default branch from master to something in Google Cloud Source repository. However, a trick that I use to reach my branch in the UI directly is by following this link:

`https://source.cloud.google.com/<project-id>/<repo-name>/+/<branch-name>`

Comment: There should be a colon at the end, otherwise you end up at the latest commit of that branch. So finish with `/<branch-name>:`, e.g. `/main:`

Comment: Still true. [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168035627?pli=1) confirms this hasn't been resolved yet as for today.

Answer (score -3):

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
```

should do the trick

Comment: That's how to do it locally. It doesn't affect the server